# With @dataclass get a dictionary of the class variable without variable fild(repr=False)

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I want to get a dictionary from the data class, but without the class variable that has the field parameter repr = False.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int = field(repr = False)

person = Person(name = 'Max', age=42)
print(asdict(person))
```

What I get:

```
{'name': 'Max', 'age': 42}
```

what I want:

```
{'name': 'Max'}
```

My solution was to create new method like:

```
def dict_without_repr_field(self) -> dict:
    dict_to_show = self.__dict__.copy()
    for key in self.__dict__.keys():
        if not self.__dataclass_fields__[key].repr:
            dict_to_show.pop(key)
    return dict_to_show
```

Is there a simpler, nicer or better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, you're doing exactly the right thing. Some small improvements can be made to make it a little more idiomatic:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int = field(repr = False)


    def asdict_considering_repr(self) -> dict:
        return {k: v for k, v in asdict(self).items() if self.__dataclass_fields__[k].repr}
```

Note that `asdict` will unroll any nested dataclasses into dictionaries as well. If you don't want that, use `vars` instead.

Comment: Warning: this won't handle nesting correctly.  Will be fine with the flat `Person` class in OP though.

Comment: @wim Right - sometimes I forget `asdict` will unroll nested dataclasses. I'll add some info.